# pgf's and pstricks's opacity is not working

Tags: tikz-pgf, pstricks, transparency, ghostscript, ps2pdf

I've recently upgraded  (on Ubuntu 18.04 LTS) TexLive 2016 to 2017. The problem that came up is that the opacity of tikz (pgf) and of pstricks pictures is not working in .ps and .pdf files after rendering (Latex to dvi to ps to pdf).

I've tried in Texstudio, Texmaker, and Kile and the problem occurred with all three editors. I've tried  evince and okular and the problem occurred in both viewers. On the other hand in Qtikz and in Texstudio's preview, opacity is working fine for tikz.

I didn't had this problem with all previous TexLive versions.

Here is a minimal example with one tikz and one pstricks image:

```
\documentclass[10pt]{article}
\usepackage[english,greek]{babel}
\usepackage[iso-8859-7]{inputenc}
\usepackage{pstricks, pstricks-add}
\usepackage{graphicx, color}
\usepackage{pgf,tikz}

\begin{document}    

\begin{tikzpicture}[line cap=round,line join=round,x=0.5cm,y=0.5cm]
\clip(-3.6008835336224467,-3.8322994902133702) rectangle     (3.6645946388488806,2.9075908995685467);
\draw [line width=1.2pt,color=gray,fill=gray,fill opacity=0.25] (0.,0.) circle (0.75cm);
\fill[line width=1.6pt,color=blue,fill=blue,fill opacity=0.25] (0.,1.) -- (0.,-1.) -- (2.,-1.) -- (2.,1.) -- cycle;
\draw [line width=1.6pt,color=blue] (0.,1.)-- (0.,-1.);
\draw [line width=1.6pt,color=blue] (0.,-1.)-- (2.,-1.);
\draw [line width=1.6pt,color=blue] (2.,-1.)-- (2.,1.);
\draw [line width=1.6pt,color=blue] (2.,1.)-- (0.,1.);
\end{tikzpicture}


\bigskip    


\psset{xunit=0.5cm,yunit=0.5cm,algebraic=true,dimen=middle,dotstyle=o,dotsize=5pt 0,linewidth=0.8pt,arrowsize=3pt 2,arrowinset=0.25}
\begin{pspicture*}(-3.6008835336224467,-3.8322994902133702)(3.6645946388488806,2.9075908995685467)
\pscircle[linewidth=1.2pt,linecolor=gray,fillcolor=gray,fillstyle=solid,opacity=0.25](0.,0.){0.75}
\pspolygon[linewidth=1.6pt,linecolor=blue,fillcolor=blue,fillstyle=solid,opacity=0.25](0.,1.)(0.,-1.)(2.,-1.)(2.,1.)
\psline[linewidth=1.6pt,linecolor=blue](0.,1.)(0.,-1.)
\psline[linewidth=1.6pt,linecolor=blue](0.,-1.)(2.,-1.)
\psline[linewidth=1.6pt,linecolor=blue](2.,-1.)(2.,1.)
\psline[linewidth=1.6pt,linecolor=blue](2.,1.)(0.,1.)
\end{pspicture*}


\end{document}
```

The result (in both) should be

[image]

but I receive

[image]

Any ideas on how to handle this issue?

P.S. Because I have tikz and pstricks in the same document, pfdlatex isn't appropriate to compile.

Comment: If @Alex's answer has solved your problem, it is customary to accept it, see: https://tex.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers

Answer (score 27, accepted):

Ghostscript-9.52 introduced new operators for setting fill and stroke opacity (`.setconstantfillopacity`, `.setconstantstrokeopacity`), deprecating the hitherto existing `.setopacityalpha`. Starting with GS version 9.53, warning messages are produced if the old operator is used.

Furthermore, a new `gs` commandline option for activating opacity features was introduced:

> ```
> ps2pdf -dALLOWPSTRANSPARENCY myfile.ps myfile.pdf
> ```

**TikZ/pgf** example:

[image]

```latex
\documentclass[border=3pt,varwidth]{standalone}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary {patterns,shapes.symbols}

\begin{document}
%\begin{preview}
  \begin{tikzpicture}[thick,fill opacity=0.5]
    \filldraw[fill=red] (0:1cm) circle (12mm);
    \filldraw[fill=green] (120:1cm) circle (12mm);
    \filldraw[fill=blue] (-120:1cm) circle (12mm);
  \end{tikzpicture}
  \tikz {
    \begin{scope}[transparency group]
      \begin{scope}[blend mode=screen]
        \fill[red!90!black] ( 90:.6) circle (1);
        \fill[green!80!black] (210:.6) circle (1);
        \fill[blue!90!black] (330:.6) circle (1);
      \end{scope}
    \end{scope}
  }

  \begin{tikzpicture}
    \shade [left color=red,right color=blue] (-2,-1) rectangle (2,1);
    \begin{scope}[transparency group=knockout]
      \fill [white] (-1.9,-.9) rectangle (1.9,.9);
      \node [opacity=0,font=\fontencoding{T1}\fontfamily{ptm}\fontsize{45}{45}\bfseries] {Ti\emph{k}Z};
    \end{scope}
  \end{tikzpicture}
  \begin{tikzpicture}[opacity=0.5]
    \begin{scope}[transparency group]
      \draw [line width=5mm] (0,0) -- (2,2);
      \draw [line width=5mm] (2,0) -- (0,2);
    \end{scope}
  \end{tikzpicture}
%\end{preview}
  
\end{document}
```

**PSTricks** example:

[image]

```latex
\documentclass{standalone}

\usepackage{pstricks-add}

\begin{document}
\psset{fillstyle=solid,linewidth=0.1,opacity=0.4,strokeopacity=0.7}

\begin{pspicture}(-3.48,-3.06)(3.48,3.48)
  \pscircle[fillcolor=green,linecolor=green](2;135){2cm}
  \pscircle[fillcolor=red,linecolor=red](2;45){2cm}
  \pscircle[fillcolor=blue,linecolor=blue](1;-90){2cm}
\end{pspicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Interesting: does that mean transparency in PostScript is 'dead' (at least for secure ones).

Comment: @joseph Don't know. The related reports and statements are a long and difficult read. I hope these changes are temporary and will be replaced by fixing their origins.

Comment: @AlexG thanks! I changed on Texstudio and on Texmaker  Ps2Pdf command  : ps2pdf -dNOSAFER %.ps %.pdf and tikz and pstricks works fine. Although I can't make it work in Kile.

Comment: @GrigoriosKostakos Glad to hear this. As for Kile, I don't know how to adjust. I always run the tools (`latex`, `dvips`, `ps2pdf`) on the command line.

Comment: This answer saved my life. I encountered this issue after upgrading GS.

Comment: This is the answer that keeps on giving. Its been two and a half years, and it just saved me a lot of pain. Thank you

Comment: This no longer works on gs 9.52. I feel like it stopped working earlier and I found a workaround but forgot what it was.  Anyway, this solution is no longer working for me.

Comment: I am going to update the answer.

Comment: It looks like the gs developers made a breaking change to transparency handling in 9.51 (https://ghostscript.com/pipermail/gs-devel/2020-May/010295.html). I solved the problem by downgrading gs to 9.27

Comment: For 9.52, `ps2pdf -dALLOWPSTRANSPARENCY  ...` should be sufficient. **No** downgrade necessary.

Comment: @AlexG: Thank you. I will upgrade later.

Comment: I use TexMaker. The solution of Griorios Kostakos works perfectly for me. Gosh : you saved my life, thanks (the solution of AlexG doesn't work for me).

Comment: @Petros You are obviously using an outdated Ghostscript version, one between 9.26 and 9.50, which indeed require `-dNOSAFER`. But now, with, 9.52 and above, you need `-dALLOWPSTRANSPARENCY`. Have a look at the older versions of this answer; it was edited several times ;-).

Answer (score 2):

I'm using Kile.  In Kile I use the `pdflatex` command with the `-shell-escape` option. For working with opacity I have found this solution. Use the `auto-pdf` package  with this option: `\usepackage[pspdf={-dDELAYSAFER}]{auto-pst-pdf}`

Comment: Welcome to TeX.Stackexchange!