# Problem with shadow in tcolorbox with LaTeX compilation

Tags: pdftex, tcolorbox, shadows, texlive-2019

I'm using TeX Live 2019 with LaTeX compiler (in Overleaf). I have the following code:

```
\documentclass[border=2mm]{standalone}

\usepackage[many]{tcolorbox}

\begin{document}
\tcbox[enhanced,drop fuzzy shadow ]
    {This is a tcolorbox.}
\end{document}
```

but I obtained

[image]

By using pdfLaTeX compilation with TeX Live 2019 or LaTeX compilation with Tex Live 2017, I obtain the right result:

[image]

What could be the problem? How can I fix it?

Comment: With recent MikTeX installation (pdfTeX, Version 3.14159265-2.6-1.40.21 (MiKTeX 20.7)) i obtain right result. You probaly need to upgrade your TeX Live to version 2020.

Comment: @Zarko I'm using Overleaf

Comment: Ah, Overleaf is not always up-to-date with packages versions.Unfortunately.

Comment: Does latex mean you are using dvips and ps2pdf?

Comment: @Zarko It's not a package problem, it's a Ghostscript problem (https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/453780/pgfs-and-pstrickss-opacity-is-not-working)

Comment: @UlrikeFischer Yes, locally I managed to fix it by compiling `ps2pdf -dNOSAFER myfile.ps myfile.pdf` but I can´t do this in Overleaf with LaTeX compiler.

Comment: ask the overleaf support if you can pass such an option.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I copy here the answer from Overleaf Support:

> You should be able to allow transparency by adding a new file `latexmkrc` (without any file extension) into your project's top folder and adding the following line there:

```
$dvipdf = "dvipdf -dNOSAFER -dALLOWPSTRANSPARENCY %O %S %D";
```

> Note that **you shouldn't include these options when you're running the code locally on your machine**, as they are considered a security threat. In Overleaf, we run the compilations in isolated Docker containers, so there's no issue.

> This is necessary in all TeX Live images in Overleaf up to 2019. For our TeX Live 2020, we're checking options how to allo transparency in PSTricks by default.