# Problem with opacity in pstricks with TeXLive 2019

Tags: pstricks, overleaf, transparency, texlive-2019

I'm using TeX Live 2019 (in Overleaf) and I have the following code:

```
\documentclass[pstricks,border=2mm]{standalone}

\begin{pspicture}(-2.5,-0.5)(2.5,4.5)
    \pspolygon[fillstyle=solid,fillcolor=teal](2,1)(-2,1)(0,4)
    \pspolygon[fillstyle=solid,fillcolor=magenta,opacity=0.5](2,3)(-2,3)(0,0)
\end{pspicture}
```

but I obtained (LaTeX compiler)

[image]

By using Tex Live 2017, I obtain the right result:

[image]

What could be the problem? How can I fix it?

Comment: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/453780/pgfs-and-pstrickss-opacity-is-not-working is what you need.

Comment: Hi andrebant and @user213378, Tom from Overleaf Support here. Thanks for pointing this out. we'll see whether we can solve this issue for the TeX Live 2020 image in Overleaf that we are about to deploy shortly. However, we'll have to discuss whether the `-dNOSAFER` option is fine to run in our docker images. Thanks again!

Comment: @user213378 That's exactly what I needed, but I can't reproduce it in Overleaf

Comment: @yo' Thanks. Is there a way to include `-dNOSAFER` by `latexmkrc` file in Overleaf?

Comment: @MateAndres We've looked further into the issue. We'll try to make this work out of the box in our TeX Live 2020 image. For now, see the answer for the correct `latexmkrc` contents.

Comment: @MateAndres This will be included in our TeX Live 2020 image by default! Thanks again for pointing this out :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Tom from Overleaf Support here.

You should be able to allow transparency by adding a new file `latexmkrc` (without any file extension) into your project's top folder and adding the following line there:

```
$dvipdf = "dvipdf -dNOSAFER -dALLOWPSTRANSPARENCY %O %S %D";
```

Note that **you shouldn't include these options when you're running the code locally on your machine**, as they are considered a security threat. In Overleaf, we run the compilations in isolated Docker containers, so there's no issue.

This is necessary in all TeX Live images in Overleaf up to 2019. This will be available in our TeX Live 2020 image by default, allowing PSTricks transparency without additional tricks.

Comment: This answer could be added here as well: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/453780/pgfs-and-pstrickss-opacity-is-not-working

Comment: @AlexG I'm reluctant to suggesting users to add this to `latexmkrc` for the security reasons. (I don't know the details really, at Overleaf we don't need to care that much, but I feel like `NOSAFER` is called the way for a reason.)

Comment: As far as transparency is concerned, `NOSAFER` is obsolete (without effect) anyway, beginning with current Ghostscript 9.52. `ALLOWPSTRANSPARENCY` is the way to go now. It doesn't enable other security-related permissions, as `NOSAFER` would do, e. g. permission to write to files.

Comment: @AlexG Ah we currently have 9.50 in our TL2020. I'll see what can be done about this. Anyway, feel free to add my notes about `latexmkrc` from here to your answer in the other thread -- you seem to know more about the issue than I do anyway :-)