# Plot solution to differential equation

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots, diagrams

[image]

I am relatively new to LaTex and unable to plot the solution to this diff equation (been using pgfplots for my other graphics)
Id like to get it to look pretty much the same as in the image (screenshot from WolframAlpha) and would appreciate any help, whether direct or pointing me to a resource that could help me

Comment: Pkg  [`pst-ode`](https://tex.stackexchange.com/search?tab=votes&q=pst-ode%20is%3aanswer&searchOn=3) could be an option.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! This has nothing to do with Overleaf, does it?

Comment: Could you please post a link to the wolfram example, I don't quite understand the above set-up, or re-write the ODE into your question. What is the meaning of the expression above the diff. eq.?

Comment: @AlexG here is the link [link](wolframalpha.com/input?i=runge+kutta+-%281%2B0.8*cos%2810pi*y%29%29y%27%3Dy+%2C+y%280%29%3D1+from+0+to+2)

Comment: @AlexG oh, i forgot to add the stepsize but youll get the gist, ideally id want the exact solution anyways but no idea how wolfram does it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ODEs can be solved within LaTeX using package `pst-ode`. It implements the Runge-Kutta-Fehlberg method (**RKF45**) which is of 4th order with embedded 5th order for adaptive step size control. The user-provided initial stepsize (2.0/400=0.005) is therefore not crucial for precision:

[image]

Typeset twice with `lualatex`:

```
\documentclass[border=1pt,varwidth]{standalone}

\usepackage{pst-ode}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=newest}
\usepackage{mathtools}

% result table `t y'  written to Y.dat
\pstODEsolve[algebraicAll,saveData]{Y}{t | y[0]}{0.0}{2.0}{401}{1.0}{-y[0]/(1+0.8*cos(10*Pi*y[0]))}

\begin{document}

\begin{equation*}
  y^{\prime}=-\frac{y}{1 + 0.8 \cos 10 \pi y }\text{, }y(0)=1
\end{equation*}

\IfFileExists{Y.dat}{%
  \begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{axis}[
      xlabel={$t$},
      ylabel={$y$}, ylabel style={rotate=-90}
    ]

    \addplot [no markers] table {Y.dat};

    \end{axis}
  \end{tikzpicture}%
}{Rerun!}

\end{document}
```

Comment: ive tried to get it to run but it wont write the y.dat file. Since ive seen your name in questions related to that, do you know how i can enable it? Tried the solution from here by creating the latexmkrc file [link](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/558687/problem-with-opacity-in-pstricks-with-texlive-2019)

Comment: ah nvm, i found the lulatex option. thank you very much